# Wait for a request to succeed \ fail before firing up the next request (one request queue)

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I have a few requests that needs to fire one by one while depending on the previous response.
That was pretty straight forward with `NSOperation` and trying to figure out
what's the best approach here with Sessions & AFNetworking >= 3.0

```
-(void)startGet
{
    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://test.com/test?%ld",(long)test];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    NSLog(@"NUMBER: %ld",(long)test);
    [manager GET:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
           NSLog(@"task: %@",task.currentRequest.URL.absoluteString);
            } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
       //NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        test = i;
        [self startGet];
    }
}
```

The log I want to get is:

```
https://test.com/test?0
https://test.com/test?1
https://test.com/test?2
https://test.com/test?3
https://test.com/test?4
https://test.com/test?5
https://test.com/test?6
```

...

Things I've tried:

```
...
dispatch_group_t serviceGroup = dispatch_group_create();
...

-(void)startGet
    {
        NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://test.com/test?%ld",(long)test];
        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
        AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        NSLog(@"NUMBER: %ld",(long)test);
        dispatch_group_enter(serviceGroup);
        [manager GET:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
               NSLog(@"task: %@",task.currentRequest.URL.absoluteString);
               dispatch_group_leave(serviceGroup);
                } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
                dispatch_group_leave(serviceGroup);
           //NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         }];
         dispatch_group_wait(serviceGroup,DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    }
```

Although the request came out in the right order I would still get mixed responses like so:

```
https://test.com/test?4
https://test.com/test?7
https://test.com/test?1
https://test.com/test?3
```

I'm not sure if something is wrong with the code or I totally misunderstood the purpose of `dispatch_group_t` in that case.

I've digged around and saw a comment by matt from AFNetworking about integrating a simple solution using Operations & session in AF and it is soon to be public but it was over 2 years ago.

I'm trying to solve this without using nested requests or `NSOperations`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try out 2 approaches

1. Semaphore

   ```
   dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
   AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
   NSLog(@"NUMBER: %ld",(long)test);
   [manager GET:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
          dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
          NSLog(@"task: %@",task.currentRequest.URL.absoluteString);
       } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
          //NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
   }];
   dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
   ```
2. WaitUntillFinished

   ```
   [operation waitUntilFinished];
   ```

You can check for detailed implementation at below link:
    https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1804

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately semaphore will block the thread completely. While the requests need to be processed one by one the thread is still active and performs other actions. Regarding `WaitUntillFinished`, it is used on operations which I indicated I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Then why don't you use blocks/delegate for this. Once you receive the response call the next webservice. You can easily maintain the parameter in global variable or pass it as a parameter in block/delegate.